# Period between LocalDates produces wrong results

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, period, date-difference

I see that `java.time.Period` with `java.time.LocalDates` works mostly as desired and I can use it to get the duration between two dates in years, months and days but I found an example that is not working (not as I expected it), like following:

```
val test1 = LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 31)
val test2 = LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 28)
val testToday = LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 9)

val period1 = Period.between(test1, testToday)
val period2 = Period.between(test2, testToday)

L.d { "test1 = $test1 | test2 = $test2 | today = $testToday" }
L.d { "period1 = $period1 | period2 = $period2" }
```

Output is following:

```
period1 = P1M9D | period2 = P1M9D
test1 = 2023-01-31 | test2 = 2023-01-28 | today = 2023-03-09
```

**Problem**

The solution above tells me following:

- Duration between 2023-01-31 and 2023-03-09 => 1 month and 9 days (P1M9D)
- Duration between 2023-01-28 and 2023-03-09 => 1 month and 9 days (P1M9D)

=> but this is wrong, the second one should show 3 days more as duration... Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is the way [`Period.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#between(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)) performs its calculation:

> The start date is included, but the end date is not. The period is
> calculated by removing complete months, then calculating the remaining
> number of days, adjusting to ensure that both have the same sign. The
> number of months is then split into years and months based on a 12
> month year. A month is considered if the end day-of-month is greater
> than or equal to the start day-of-month. For example, from 2010-01-15
> to 2011-03-18 is one year, two months and three days.

This results in 2023-01-28 until 2023-01-01 counting as 1 month and 1 day (P1M1D), but so will 2023-01-29, 30, and 31. This is because 2023-01-31 plus 1 month is 2023-02-31, which is invalid, so it uses 2023-02-28 (and same for 29 and 30, and of course 28). In other words, there is 1 full month, which ends on 2023-02-28, and then there are 9 more days until 2023-03-09 (exclusive).

This conforms to the behaviour documented for [`LocalDate.plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths(long)):

> This method adds the specified amount to the months field in three
> steps:
>
> 1. Add the input months to the month-of-year field
> 2. Check if the resulting date would be invalid
> 3. Adjust the day-of-month to the last valid day if necessary
>
> For example, 2007-03-31 plus one month would result in the invalid
> date 2007-04-31. Instead of returning an invalid result, the last
> valid day of the month, 2007-04-30, is selected instead.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was totally aware of exclusion of the end date and of how `LocalDate.plusMonths` works (which makes sense) but when calculation the `Period` between two dates I would consider another logic as correct (I still feel like the logic is in `Period` is incorrect)  - please check the last paragraph of my question, I added what I'd consider a "natural" logic => can I get this result with `java.time` or do I need to write this logic myself?

Comment: @prom85 I have rolled back that edit, because that is known as "moving the goalposts". In any case, I'm not aware of a "standard" way of doing this.

Comment: that's ok. It just did not fit into a comment... Thanks for answering it.

Comment: The “correct” way to calculate months and days across months of uneven lengths and involving dates near the end of the month is a never-ending discussion. Each date library typically has its own way. I believe that no way exists that would be considered correct and adequate for all purposes and would satisfy everyone.

Comment: And it shouldn’t be too hard to hand code a method that calculates it in the way that you prefer and stuffs the result into a `Period`.